# Can I display images with img tag for AMP version

Tags: wordpress, image, mobile, amp-html

I have a WordPress blog and i'm using "mobble plugin" to generate the mobile version.
I'm going to use the same plugin to generate the AMP.
the issue is the embed images are using "img" tag not "amp-img" tag.

is it possible using "img" tag with some images in AMP version?

what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use img tag directly in amp version

> AMP HTML files don't support the normal HTML img tag. With amp-img AMP provides a powerful replacement.

Please refer : [**amp-img**](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-img/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace the `img` with `amp-img` in amp version of your website.

Here, it is an example of `amp-img` tag (Attributes defined in following declaration are mandatory for passing amp validation).

`<amp-img src="welcome.jpg" alt="Welcome" height="400" width="800"></amp-img>`